# insert and update same table with different data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table1 like below

```
AccNum  ProdId  Name    Work
1       P1      DJ     sample
2       P2      SJ      W1
2       C2      SJ      W1
```

If we have AccNum is 1, i need to insert below record with ProdId C1 (the same row for "P1 with "C1" product)

```
1   C1  DJ  sample
```

So the result will be

```
 AccNum     ProdId  Name    Work
    1       P1      DJ     sample
    2       P2      SJ      W1
    1       C1      DJ      sample
    2       C2      SJ      W1
```

Case2:

If we have data like below

```
 AccNum     ProdId  Name    Work
    1       P1      DJ     sample
    2       P2      SJ      W1
    1       C1      DJ      
    2       C2      SJ      W1
```

I need to update C1 with work 'sample' and result like below

```
AccNum  ProdId  Name    Work
    1       P1      DJ     sample
    2       P2      SJ      W1
    1       C1      DJ      sample
    2       C2      SJ      W1
```

If table1 has 100's of rows, i need to check for each P1 row, i need to insert or update C1 data.

I need to handle both the cases, any one please suggest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look into SQL triggers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName ON table
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table
        WHERE AccNum= (SELECT AccNum FROM Inserted)
      )
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table SET Table.Work = inserted.work 
    FROM inserted where table.AccNum = inserted.AccNum
GO
```

I haven't tested this code but it will be something like this.

Or this

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (AccNum int,  ProdId varchar(10),  Name varchar(10),    Work varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #Table1 (AccNum, ProdId, Name, Work) VALUES (1,'P1','DJ','Sample')
INSERT INTO #Table1 (AccNum, ProdId, Name, Work) VALUES (2,'P2','SJ','W1')
INSERT INTO #Table1 (AccNum, ProdId, Name, Work) VALUES (1,'C1','DJ','Sample')
INSERT INTO #Table1 (AccNum, ProdId, Name, Work) VALUES (2,'C2','SJ','W1')

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_sproc 
(@ProdId varchar(10), @Work varchar(10))
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @cRec varchar(10) = STUFF(@ProdId,1,1,'C')

UPDATE #Table1 SET Work = @Work WHERE ProdId = @ProdId

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Table1 WHERE ProdId = @cRec)
    UPDATE #Table1 SET Work = @Work WHERE ProdId = @cRec
ELSE
    INSERT INTO #Table1(AccNum, ProdId, Name, Work) SELECT AccNum, @cRec, Name,@Work FROM #Table1 WHERE ProdId =@ProdId
END
GO

SELECT * FROM #Table1

EXEC usp_sproc 'P1','TESTw'

DROP PROCEDURE usp_sproc
```

Comment: Thanks @ClassyBear, I cann't use trigger , i need to implement this to Storedprocedure

Comment: Even better. Same logic as the code but you wont have to join with the inserted table. Run your insert first to update the table with the record and then run the `if` statement above with the params that you need updated.

Comment: If table1 has 100's of rows, i need to check for each P1 row, i need to insert or update C1 data.